# Filter View Visibility

Tags: community, salesforce1-app, filters

I have a filter view on salesforce custom object which i want to make visible for external user and not internal users profile. Selected the view for partner users, if works but still it is availbale for internal users

Comment: It's always available to System Administrators and users with Manage Public List Views. Did you try with a normal user that doesn't have extra permissions?

Comment: I have one view, for which i selected it to be visible for "All Partner Users" but it is still available for Internal users. So, can you suggest, what i am missing here. Thankx